# why can't i access CategoryName in this example?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.1, navigation-properties

Consider the following classes:

```
public class Pie
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Pie> Pies { get; set; }
}
```

I have the following data coming from hardcoded files:

```
public class MockPieRepository : IPieRepository
{
    private readonly ICategoryRepository _categoryRepository = new MockCategoryRepository();

    private List<Pie> pies = new List<Pie>() {
        new Pie { Id = 1, Name = "Apple Pie", Price = 12.95M, IsPieOfTheWeek = true, ShortDescription = "Yummy Apple Pie", LongDescription = "Lengthy apple pie", ImageThumbnailUrl = "images/thumbs/apple.jpg", ImageUrl = "images/apple.jpg", CategoryId = 1},
        new Pie { Id = 2, Name = "Rhubarb Pie", Price = 11.95M, IsPieOfTheWeek = false, ShortDescription = "Yummy Rhubarb Pie", LongDescription = "Lengthy Rhubarb pie", ImageThumbnailUrl = "images/thumbs/Rhubarb.jpg", ImageUrl = "images/Rhubarb.jpg", CategoryId = 1},
        new Pie { Id = 3, Name = "Cheesecake", Price = 8.95M, IsPieOfTheWeek = false, ShortDescription = "Yummy Cheesecake Pie", LongDescription = "Lengthy Cheesecake pie", ImageThumbnailUrl = "images/thumbs/Cheesecake.jpg", ImageUrl = "images/Cheesecake.jpg", CategoryId = 2},
        new Pie { Id = 4, Name = "Chocolate Cake", Price = 4.95M, IsPieOfTheWeek = false, ShortDescription = "Yummy Chocolate Pie", LongDescription = "Lengthy Chocolate pie", ImageThumbnailUrl = "images/thumbs/Chocolate.jpg", ImageUrl = "images/Chocolate.jpg", CategoryId = 3},
        new Pie { Id = 5, Name = "Mince Beef", Price = 6.99M, IsPieOfTheWeek = false, ShortDescription = "Yummy Mince Beef Pie", LongDescription = "Lengthy Mince Beef pie", ImageThumbnailUrl = "images/thumbs/Beef.jpg", ImageUrl = "images/Beef.jpg", CategoryId = 3}
    };

    public IEnumerable<Pie> GetPies()
    {
        return pies.OrderBy(p => p.Id);
    }
    public Pie GetPieById(int pieId)
    {
        return pies.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == pieId);
    }


}

public class MockCategoryRepository : ICategoryRepository
{
    public IEnumerable<Category> Categories {
        get {
            return new List<Category>
            {
                new Category { CategoryId = 1, CategoryName = "Fruit Pies", Description = "All fruity pies"},
                new Category { CategoryId = 2, CategoryName = "Cheesecakes", Description = "Cheesecakes to make your heart sing"},
                new Category { CategoryId = 3, CategoryName = "Seasonal Pies", Description = "Christmas, Halloween or Spring"}
            };
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to get CategoryName from @pie.Category.CategoryName the value is null. Clearly I'm doing something wrong trying to navigate to Category from Pie, but can anyone tell me what it is?

Thanks.

Comment: I see no `@pie.Category.CategoryName` in your code.

Comment: I assume that you assume by referencing the category (e.g. by setting `CategoryId = 1`) the category is automatically applied to the `Pie`, which isn´t the case. You surely have to apply the category with that id yourself to the `Pie`. Something like `myPie = new Pie { Category = getCategoryById(categoryId) }`.

Comment: And what is `@pie` in the first place? Is there an error? Something else?

Comment: @HimBromBeere yes, this is what i was getting at. previously i have used database with entity framework and I was able to make a the association between pie and category. clearly this hasn't happened here as i expected it would. no problem. thanks for taking the time

Answer (score 1):

You never set `pie.Category = category`.

One of the things that EF will automatically do when it loads data, is that it will 'resolve' navigation properties that it has detected in the data.

If you save `pie` with a `Category` set, then that data will be persisted in the database, and next time `pie` is loaded, you will have `pie.Category` also loaded.  As you haven't stored (and retrieved) data from a database, this has not happened.

Comment: thanks for taking the time. i'm not using the database but rather in memory. i realise now what i'm try to explain, won't work.